# 433 Mhz transmitter on RPI always sending 00000000

Tags: remote, sensor, radio

I've bought a Realtek RTL2832 DBV for my RPI to read 433 mhz data and a transmitter HM-T433. I can successfully receive messages from two 433mhz remotes with the rtl_433 utility, but when I try to send any data I am always getting readings like

```
[00] {0} 00 : 00000000
```

I've tried sending the data trough the ninjablock utility, RCSwitch, pilight, custom code and a lot more of other possibilities but all readings from rtl_433 are bits of 0.

Is this normal? Is there something wrong with the transmitter (how can I check that)? Am I not reading the data correctly?

Comment: [piscope](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html) will show you data being sent and received.

Comment: What antenna are you using with the HM-T433?

Comment: I have a 10cm wired soldered to the transmitter. The RTL2832 DBV  receiver is near the transmitter, I've tried from 2cm distance to 1m and still the same.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mixing up signal moldulations.

HM-T433 uses [FSK (Fequency Shift Keying)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency-shift_keying).

Most applications in 443MHz use [ASK (Amplitude Shift Keying)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude-shift_keying) and of those most use [OOK (On/Off Keying)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-off_keying). That means they either send a signal with constant amplitude and frequency for "1" and don't send anything at all for 0.

RTL2832 is capable of doing both FSK and ASK. But you have to configure it correctly for your application. The rtl_433 utility is fitted for ASK/OOK so your transmitter does not match. You will need to find another utility that uses FSK.

Try [GQRX](http://gqrx.dk/download) to find out if you receive the signal at all.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.quasaruk.co.uk/acatalog/Data_Transmisson_Modules.html) site says that HM-T433 is a perfect match for [HM-R433](http://www.hestore.hu/prod_10031828.html?lang=en). The other one is most likely a just a demodulator/TV tuner. Do you have receive modules?

EDIT: TRY FLIPPING THE TX/RX PINS

Comment: I have only the HM-T433. The thing is that with another transmitter (cheap Chinese one) all is working fine.

Comment: Why not use that?

Comment: That's not mine :) I've borrowed from a friend of mine.

Comment: @AliCornea Then buy one yourself, since it's a cheap one.